# Update-Database Doesn't Create Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have 5 tables in SQL and created with Entity Framework.
But it doesn't create table anymore.

My context:

```
 public class PlakappContext:DbContext
 {
        public DbSet<UserModel> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostModel> Post { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PlateModel> Plate { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostPlateModel> PostPlate { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostImageModel> PostImage { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostVoteModel> PostVote { get; set; }
}
```

When I use `Update-Database` command in PMC it doesn't return an error. It returns "Running Seed Method"

But it doesn't create the table in SQL Server.

I tried:

```
Enable-Migrations

Add-Migration Initial
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges

Update-Database
Update-Database -Verbose
```

I created all the tables but can't do it for `PostVote`.

Also `PostVoteModel`:

```
   public class PostVoteModel
   {
        [Key]
        public int VoteId { get; set; }
        public int VoteStatus { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
   }
```

**UPDATE:**

Migration.cs:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

Configuration.cs:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : 

    DbMigrationsConfiguration<Plakapp.Data.PlakappContext>
        {
            public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            }

            protected override void Seed(Plakapp.Data.PlakappContext context)
            {
                //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

                //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
                //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: @JohnNyingi I don't get any error. Update-Database command working. So, it returning "Running seed method." but it doesn't create the table in sql

Comment: Can you show us your `Configuration.cs` and `Migration` files. Additionally some tools need to compile code for detecting new migrations. You can try to build app and after than run `Update-Database` command.

Comment: Do you have a migration for PostVoteModel?

Comment: @AdemCatamak I've added configuration.cs and 123_Initial.cs

Comment: Try `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`